# HTML to PHP form inputs through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I want to get the inputs from an html form, and send them to PHP through my JavaScript. Basically I have a very simple html form, and I would like to grab it's inputs and send them to PHP with JavaScript as I'm using AJAX.

The problem is that whenever I fill out the form and I submit it, it just send me an email BUT without the values from the form - just what I already have in the PHP.

**HTML Code**

```html
<!-- CONTACT FORM START -->
<form id="contact-form" class="fade-up" method="post" action="">
    <div class="row">

        <!--NAME FIELD-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="cf-name" class="input__field cf-validate" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>

        <!--EMAIL FIELD-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="cf-email" class="input__field cf-validate" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <!--MESSAGE BOX-->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea id="cf-message" class="input__field cf-validate" rows="8" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="alert-container col-md-12"></div>

        <!--SUBMIT BUTTON-->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" id="cf-submit" name="subind" class="main-btn cursor-link">Send as an individual</button>

            <button type="submit" id="cf-submit" name="subbiz" class="main-btn cursor-link">Send as a business</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
<!-- CONTACT FORM END -->
```

**Javascript Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        
        var name = document.getElementById('cf-name').value
        var email = document.getElementById('cf-email').value
        var msg = document.getElementById('cf-message').value
        
        //make a post request by AJAX
        
        $.post("mail.php",{name:name,email:email,msg:msg},function(data){
            console.log(data)
        })
    })
})
```

**PHP Code**

```php
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];echo $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];echo $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['msg'];echo $_POST['msg'];
    $subject = "Client Mail - Individual";
    $to = "clients@growpile.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$email;
    $txt = "Name: ".$name." - Individual"."\n"."From: ".$email."\n\n".$message."\n\n".$ind;

    mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: So what is the problem you're experiencing? are you getting any errors? You haven't specified what you need help with exactly.

Comment: Whoops, so the emails that I'm sending to myself don't have any of the data I entered in the form. They're just the template with empty spaces where the values should be.

Answer (score -1):

Adjust your form so that there is no action associated with it, this is to prevent the form submitting a POST request before the Javascript can execute.

```html
<!-- CONTACT FORM START -->
<form id="contact-form" class="fade-up">
    <div class="row">

        <!--NAME FIELD-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="cf-name" class="input__field cf-validate" name="cf-name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>

        <!--EMAIL FIELD-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="cf-email" class="input__field cf-validate" name="cf-email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <!--MESSAGE BOX-->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea id="cf-message" class="input__field cf-validate" rows="8" name="ccf-message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="alert-container col-md-12"></div>

        <!--SUBMIT BUTTON-->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" id="cf-submit" name="subind" class="main-btn cursor-link">Send as an individual</button>

            <button type="submit" id="cf-submit" name="subbiz" class="main-btn cursor-link">Send as a business</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

You can obtain the input of the HTML fields using JQuery's `val()` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        
        var name = $("#cf-name").val();
        var email = $("#cf-email").val();
        var message = $("#cf-message").val();
        
        // Make a post request by AJAX.
        $.post("mail.php", {name: name, email: email, message: message}, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

As for your server-sided POST request handler, you grab the input from the POST request using the [filter_input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function under the index of the variable.

```php
<?php
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name");
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email");
    $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "message");

    // Print the information from the form received.
    echo "Name: " . $name . "\n";
    echo "Email: " . $email . "\n";
    echo "Message: " . $message;

    $subject = "Client Mail - Individual";
    $to = "clients@growpile.com";
    $headers = "From: " . $email;
    $txt = "Name: " . $name . " - Individual" . "\n" . "From: " . $email . "\n\n" . $message . "\n\n" . $ind;

    mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks just tried that, but it does not seem like it's working. Also now that I checked the console ( f12 ) it looks like the values we dumped there are empty? Could it be from my html? pic: https://imgur.com/a/03wIxOZ

Comment: Can you confirm you are using jQuery?

Comment: Also, try removing the `method="post" action=""` in your `<form>` tag in case this is still triggering its own post request before the JS gets triggered. I have tested the code and it gives me a valid result. https://i.imgur.com/DIfuU1k.png

Comment: Yeah, I have "<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>" just before the "</body>" tag.

Comment: I have updated my answer to the code I am testing which is working.

Comment: @NickKazakov and where do you have your _own_ code? Did you embed that _after_ jQuery? Otherwise, `$` will not exist when you try to access it, causing an error, and letting your form submission proceed the normal way.